# Is it possible for the Enumerable.FirstOrDefault method to deal with null parameters

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

Can this code be written so that items in the list with a parent property of null will be returned when comparing to an object (x) that also has a null Parent?

```
MyObject obj = objList.FirstOrDefault(o => n.Parent.Equals(x.Parent));
```

Assuming the "Equals" method is correctly overridden, this fails where there is an item in the "objList" with a null Parent - with an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." exception.

*I would assume that occurs because if n.Parent is null, you can't call its Equal method.*

Anyway, I currently resorted this this approach:

```
MyObject obj = null;
foreach (MyObject existingObj in objList)
{
    bool match = false;

    if (x.Parent == null)
    {
        if (existingObj.Parent == null)
        {
            match = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (existingObj.Parent != null)
        {
            if (x.Parent.Equals(existingObj.Parent))
            {
                match = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if (match)
    {
        obj= existingObj;
        break;
    }
```

So while it does work, it's not very elegant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `FirstOrDefault`, but it is a common problem that is solved by the static `Object.Equals` method. You want:

```
MyObject obj = objList.FirstOrDefault(o => Object.Equals(o.Parent, x.Parent));
```

Incidentally, that method looks something like this:

```
public static bool Equals(Object objA, Object objB) 
{
    // handle situation where both objects are null or both the same reference
    if (objA == objB)
        return true;
    // both are not null, so if any is null they can't be equal
    if (objA == null || objB == null)
        return false; 
    // nulls are already handled, so it's now safe to call objA.Equals
    return objA.Equals(objB);
}
```

Even if that method didn't exist, you could still write your assignment this way:

```
MyObject obj = objList.FirstOrDefault(x.Parent == null ?
    o => o.Parent == null :
    o => x.Parent.Equals(o.Parent));
```

That uses a different lambda depending on whether `x.Parent` is null. If it's null, it just has to look for objects whose `Parent` is null. If not, it's always safe to call `x.Parent.Equals` and uses a lambda that does so.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `object.Equals` instead.

```
MyObject obj = objList.FirstOrDefault(o => object.Equals(n.Parent, x.Parent));
```

`object.Equals` will use the first parameters `Equal` override so long as both parameters are not null.